# Multi level user Login

Tags: android, multi-level

I have a project to make login page with multi level user login in android studio using SQLite database on phone, and i only can made basic login app, do you guys have some reference for this problem? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

This the code for user level:

```
if (databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString.trim(), text InputEditTextPassword.getText().toString.trim())) //when user successfully login
{
     Cursor userLevel;
     userLevel.databaseHelper.checkAdmin(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()); //get user level from database userLevel.moveToFirst();
     int level = userLevel.getInt(0); //convert Cursor data to Int if(level==1){ //go to userActivity.class
}
else
{
    // go to registerActivity.class
}
```

and this code for get user level from database:

```
public Cursor checkAdmin(String email)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select level from "+ TABLE_USER+ "where email ="+email, null);
    return res;
}
```

Any idea where are my mistake?

Comment: u need to use firebase to make multi level user login. cannot use inbuilt sqlite

Comment: which kind of multi level login you want? Where you want to login to? And how does it relate to SQLite at all?

Comment: if multiple user register into app and data store into register table then after all that user login time match password and id into register table

Comment: `... i only can made basic login app...` Then you're already on the right path. Just give a integer (permission id) and when you log in, use that number to determine what your user can or can't do (i.e.: -1 = admin and has no restriction, user 0 = power user and you disable a few buttons, 1 = normal user who can do limited things, ... 9 is a visitor and can only see things). No need to use fancy things like Firebase or whatever.

Comment: i did it @KlingKlang Klang , another problem come in, i add this code for the user level, in this case when user had level 1 they will go to user page and level 2 they will go to registration page, i think the problem in how to get user level from SQLite, i had convert the cursor to int data, but when i try to login the application will close suddenly. any idea?

Comment: this the code for user level :
if (databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString.trim(), text InputEditTextPassword.getText().toString.trim())) //when user successfully login { 
Cursor userLevel;
userLevel.databaseHelper.checkAdmin(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()); //get user level from database
userLevel.moveToFirst(); 
int level = userLevel.getInt(0); //convert Cursor data to Int
if(level==1){
//go to userActivity.class}
else{
//go to registerActivity.class}

Comment: and this code for get user level from database :

public Cursor checkAdmin(String email){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select level from "+ TABLE_USER+ "where email ="+email, null);
return res;
}

any idea where are my mistake?

Comment: You're simply not doing this part right. You understood the logic (which is critical). You simply have to find out which is the correct implementation in practice.

Comment: As far as I can spot: **1** - this: `userLevel.databaseHelper....` means nothing and will cause an error. **2** - this: `+ TABLE_USER+ "where email ="` needs a **space** before the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: sorry i made mistake, the code should be like this : `userLevel = databaseHelper.checkAdmin(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());` i just save userLevel from database to userLevel variable and convert it to integer. i had add space before where, but it still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys, i had finish my project, the mistake was in the query, i missed double qoutes in `WHERE` condition, the code shoulde be like this:

```
public Cursor checkAdmin (String email){
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT user_level FROM"+TABLE_USER+" WHERE user_email = \""+email+"\"",null);
  return res;
  }
```

and all we have to do is convert res to integer then use this code :

```
 if (databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString.trim(), text InputEditTextPassword.getText().toString.trim())) 
{ //when user successfully login
  Cursor userLevel;
  userLevel = databaseHelper.checkAdmin(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()); //get user level from database 
  userLevel.moveToFirst(); //convert Cursor data to Int
  int level = userLevel.getInt(0); //convert Cursor data to Int 
  if(level==1){ 
     //go to userActivity.class
  }
  else
  {
    //go to registerActivity.class
  }
```

Thanks guys, hope this code can help you all.